# How to change dataflow job graph during runtime with arguments?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using Dataflow to read data from a JDBC table and load results to a BigQuery table. There is one parameter "flag" that I want to pass during runtime and if the flag is set `True`, results should be loaded to an additional table in BigQuery.
To summarise:

1. If the flag is set `False` - Read table A from JDBC, write to table A in BigQuery
2. If the flag is set `True` - Read table A from JDBC, write to table A as well as B in BigQuery.

Please refer sample code of my pipeline

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);
  Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
  ValueProvider < String > gcsFlag = options.getGcsFlag();

  PCollection < TableRow > inputData = pipeline.apply("Reading JDBC Table",
    JdbcIO. < TableRow > read()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
      .create(options.getDriverClassName(), options.getJdbcUrl())
      .withUsername(options.getUsername()).withPassword(options.getPassword()))
    .withQuery(options.getSqlQuery())
    .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
    .withRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper()));
  inputData.apply(
    "Write to BigQuery Table 1",
    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
    .withoutValidation()
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory())
    .to(options.getOutputTable()));
  if (gcsFlag.get().equals("TRUE")) {

    inputData.apply(
      "Write to BigQuery Table 2",
      BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
      .withoutValidation()
      .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
      .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory())
      .to(options.getOutputTable2()));
  }
  pipeline.run();
}
```

The challenge that I am facing is I have to pass the `ValueProvider` during compiling and creating the dataflow template. The job graph is constructed at compile time only and I am not able to re-use the same template again for other cases.

Is there a way that I can pass the `ValueProvider<String> flag` at runtime and the job graph can be constructed during runtime? With this, I can reuse the same template for both cases. Similarly, I want to also provide `sqlQuery` (options.getSqlQuery()) at runtime. So that I can use the same template for all the tables that I want to read from Source.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the DAG it can't change in the runtime.

But still, you have a chance to fix your problem. Try Beam Partition-Pattern
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/partition/